# Testing for presence of UTF-8 character in JQuery string failing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a JQuery function that will test a string for the presence of a specific UTF-8 Character.

In this case the character is `U+00AD` (*Soft Hyphen*).

Here is one variation of the function I've tried, but just can't find a working solution.

```
var index = obj.value.indexOf($('&#x00ad;').text());
var isMatch = index >= 0;

if (isMatch) {
    //Do match work
}
```

Can anyone suggest a fix; or something else; I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *unicode* character; UTF8 is just an encoding.

You can put the character directly in the string.  However, since it's invisible, it would be more readable to use a Javascript escape sequence: `"\u00AD"`

Comment: I changed it to `var index = obj.value.indexOf('\u00AD');` and that worked... Thanks.